expand pandas dataframe column to multiple columns
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:



A
B




[1,2]
X


[3,4]
Y



I want it to look like:



A_0
A_1
B




1
2
X


3
4
Y



What would be the best way to do this?
I tried this:
col = "A"
max_len = df.apply(lambda row: len(row[col_to_expand]), axis = 1).max() # gets max length of the list
labels = [ col + "_" + str(i) for i in range(max_len) ] #create output labels
df[labels] = df[col]


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. There's an existing question about this. If it's not what you're looking for, please clarify what you mean by "best". For more tips, check out How to ask a good question. You can [edit] if needed.

Code
tmp = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].tolist()).add_prefix('A_')

tmp:
    A_0 A_1
0   1   2
1   3   4

concat tmp & original df (except colum 'A')
out = pd.concat([tmp, df.drop('A', axis=1)], axis=1)

out:
   A_0  A_1  B
0    1    2  X
1    3    4  Y

